# Large numbers on calculator screen expanding past boundaries

Tags: css, reactjs, calculator, create-react-app

I have created a calculator in create-react-app and I'm having an issue with the numbers flowing off the screen.

For example, when you type 11111111111111111111111111111111 the numbers will continue outside of the calculator output. I would like for the large numbers to shrink down and contain themselves within the space. How can this be achieved?

I have tried implementing https://github.com/kennethormandy/react-fittext as a dependency but it only appears to make my numbers smaller. The numbers still continue off the screen even with this implemented. I have included a current sandbox version of the project, so that you may see what I'm referring to. https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-haslett-8vf8s

You can find where I have used the above dependency in the output display component.

This is the CSS I use to style the calculator output

```
.output {
    grid-column-start: span 4;
    color: $white;
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: flex-end; 
    align-items: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#answer{
    margin-right: 12px; 
    font-size: 5vh;
    font-family: 'Lexend Tera', sans-serif;
      }
```

and this is the component class in question.

```
import React from 'react';
import FitText from '@kennethormandy/react-fittext'

class OutputDisplay extends React.Component{


    render(props){
        return <p className='output'><span id='answer'><FitText compressor={0.1}>{this.props.placeThisOnScreen}</FitText></span></p>
    }
}

export default OutputDisplay;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide overflowed text and set text direction to rtl:

```
#answer {
  overflow: hidden;

  > div {
    direction: rtl;
  }
}
```

With breaking string:

```
#answer {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: This is a good plan B solution, but this solution hides the numbers instead of shrinking them down. I would like for the large numbers to shrink down and contain themselves within the space.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS `word-wrap: normal` and define the size of the calculator screen (output) window according to your needs.

Comment: I tried using word-wrap: normal in my #answer selector and it didn't wrap around in the contained space. The width is already defined in the .baseboard selector.